# How to check if a linked list is a palindrome or not in Java?

Tags: java, reference, linked-list, parameter-passing

I wrote a code to check if a singly linked list is a palindrome. And I made two steps:

1st. reverse the original linked list.

2nd. Check if the original and reversed linked list have the same element.

```
    public static Boolean isPalindrome(Node input){
        Node reversed= reverse(input);
        while (input!=null){
            if(input.item!=reversed.item)
                return false;
            input=input.next;
            reversed=reversed.next;
            }
            return true;
    }
    static Node head;
    public static Node reverse(Node input){
        if(input==null || input.next==null){
            head=input;
            return input;
        }
        else{
            reverse(input.next);
            input.next.next=input;
            input.next=null;
            return head;
        }
    }
```

This program works. But I thought, when execute the reverse method, since the original linked list's head gets passed in, so the original linked list might changed as well, so the isPalindrome should also return true, right ? Am I right or can you tell me if I misunderstood any concept? thanks

This is the main function and how I use that code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Node a=new Node(9);
    Node b=new Node(8);
    Node c=new Node(7);
    Node d=new Node(6);
    a.next=b;
    b.next=c;
    c.next=d;
    //d.next=c;
    Boolean tf=isPalindrome(a);
    if (tf)
        System.out.println("Is Palindrome!");
    else
        System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code showing how do you call these methods?

Comment: yean, sure  . I just use a print clause:Boolean tf=isPalindrome(a);
  if (tf)
   System.out.println("Is Palindrome!");
  else
   System.out.println("Not Palindrome");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your method is *not* working. Try it for a list that contains `3,4,5,3`. It will return `true`.

Also, it changes the list that was passed to it, which is not a very good idea. If you do something like `System.out.println(a)` (assuming you wrote a proper `toString()` method) after you run your method, you'll be surprised to find that it only has one item...

This is indeed because passing an object reference is like passing a pointer in languages like `C`. If you change the content of that object (and ultimately you do, because in `reverse` you put `null` in its `next`), then it stays changed.

So why does your program return `true`? Because `input`, as I said, becomes a one-item list. `reversed` contains the full reversed list, and `input` merely points to its last item. Since you loop on `input`, then **if the first and last items are the same**, you'll get `true` - whether or not the list is a palindrome. That's because you only iterate on the one item that `input` is pointing to.

Comment: Yeah, Got it ! thanks so much. I saw the mistake I made . When I reverse the original linked list, the original "head's" next is set to be null . So it became an one element linked list. And now, "input" is just the first element of the original list, and "reversed" is the whole reversed list. For the while loop, it will only check the first item  with the last item then terminate ! You're right, thanks so much !