# Checking if a linked List a Palindrome using a Node Class

Tags: java

I have a project issue where I need to check if a linked list is a palindrome, the same forward as it is backward.  I was given a class titled a Node class that contains specific information that I am not allowed to change so I must use what I have in that class and cant write more there to help me.  My problem is I can get through the list, but I don't know how to go backwards through and compare values.

Disclaimer:  I don't want a complete answer just tips/ideas!

Here is the class I can't change and have to work with:

```
class Node {
    /**
     *  The value stored in the node.
     */
    public Character value;

    /**
     *  A pointer to the next node in
     *  the list.
     */
    public Node next;

    /**
     *  A pointer to the previous node
     *  in the list. (Note: having this
     *  pointer makes this a "doubly linked"
     *  list.
     */
    public Node prev;

    /**
     *  A constructor to set up a
     *  node with a value.
     *  
     *  @param value the value to put in the node
     */
    public Node(Character value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     *  A constructor to set up a
     *  node with a value and a pointer
     *  to the previous node (so I can
     *  append items easily in my test
     *  code).
     *  
     *  @param value the value to put in the node
     *  @param prev the previous node in the list
     */
    public Node(Character value, Node prev) {
        this.value = value;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    /**
     *  Sets the next node in the list.
     *  
     *  @param n the next node in the list
     */
    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }

    /**
     *  Sets the previous node in the list.
     *  
     *  @param n the previous node in the list
     */
    public void setPrev(Node n) {
        prev = n;
    }
}
```

So far this is what I have and I am just trying whatever I can:

```
public static boolean listPalindrome(Node input) {

        if(input == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        int count = 0;

        while(input.next != null)
        {
            count++;
        }

        Node holder = new Node(null, input.next);

        for(int i = 0;i<count;i++)
        {
            if(input.next != null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        return false; //replace this
    }
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a linked list is a palindrome or not in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129232/how-to-check-if-a-linked-list-is-a-palindrome-or-not-in-java)

Comment: I was checking that, but it wasn't quite giving me an idea like I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop with `count++`. `input.next` will always be non-null since you aren't updating the value of `input` in the loop.

If you were to get past that there is no reason to declare a `new Node` in your code. The loop you have also will break on the first iteration assuming the linked list is a size > 0, you should instead check `input.next == null` but put it at the end of the loop.

Also noting that your a GMU student it would be an honor code violation for me to help you any more than this ;)

Comment: Thank you for that I wanted just an idea rather than an answer, I did not know where to start!

Comment: I fixed that in the post so it is known.