# Check if a linked list is a palindrome

Tags: javascript, linked-list, pass-by-reference, palindrome

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    if(head === null){
        return true;
    }
    var current, runner;
    current = head;
    runner = head;
    runner = reverseList(runner);
    while(current !== null && runner !== null){
        if(current.val != runner.val){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            current = current.next;
            runner = runner.next;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Here's my reverse function. This is where I believe I'm having the most issue. I am having a similar issue to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129232/how-to-check-if-a-linked-list-is-a-palindrome-or-not-in-java), but I'm not exactly sure how to fix the object reference problem.

```
var reverseList = function(head){
    var previous, current, next;
    current = head;
    previous = null;
    next = null;
    while(current !== null){
        next = current.next;
        current.next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = previous;
    return previous;
}
```

Giving an input of [1, 3, 4, 5, 1] returns true, so I believe running the reverse function is only returning a single node in the linked list.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _I believe running the reverse function is only returning a single node_. Instead of believe things, you could check by yourself if reversList is wrong or not. So, you could ask directly for a malfunctioning revere list instead of asking where is the bug in the whole algorithm.

Comment: `[1, 3, 4, 5, 1]` ain't a linked list. How exactly do you call the function? What value are you passing to the function?

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs in your setup here that I'll point you towards... if you'd like an answer for how to fix them, I can give you those, but since this looks like a learning problem I'll simply point you in the right direction.

The first bug is indeed in your reverseList function, but not because it is only returning a single node. The problem is that you are passing the original list by reference, and then manipulating it, so while at the end of reverseList `runner` contains [1, 5, 4, 3, 1] as you expect, `head` no longer contains [1, 3, 4, 5, 1]. You need to look at how to generate a reverse list without destroying your initial list...

Second, the logic after reversal within `isPalindrome` *assumes* that the two lists will be the same length, but will return true if one list is merely a prefix of the other (for example, if `head` happens to be only [1] after your manipulations and `runner` contains [1, 5, 4, 3, 1])

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for being helpful.